# z-index on fixed header not working

Tags: html, css

I have tried to replicate the issue in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5sjZkTm5oeRmGKCVE3q?p=preview).

```
.demo-blog.mdl-layout .mdl-layout__content {
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -80px;
    z-index: 100;
}

header.main-header{
  z-index: -50;
}
```

I want the div that says "on the road again" to be on top of the header that says "evolution update". I have tried changing the parent's z-index, changing each related unit's z-index, wrap header within a div tag, and yet nothing works. The "on the road again" div is still beneath the header.

What is I want is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQ3v.png).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You need to set the header to a `position` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index...!

Answer (score 1):

Used to `z-index` with `position` without `position` this is not working.

The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element.

**Note:** `z-index` only works on **positioned elements** `(position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem is you need to add `margin-top: -60px;` to `.demo-blog`